# Lithium Ion Battery Model in LTSpice

Tags: batteries, ltspice, modeling

I am looking for a model I can use in LTspice for a a Lithium Ion battery.  It is a pulsed load and I want to see things like heat losses and discharge time. Is there an existing model I can utilize for this, how can a li-ion battery be simulated in lt spice?

I am using a Saft 7s2p battery.

Comment: Try the [LTspice group's](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/) `Files` area. If you search for `Li-Ion` you'll get some results.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks this was a nice resource I didn't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a scheme like this:

It uses a seperate circuit to simulate the battery. The problem will be deriving the values for the battery that you have, the values for the series resistance , and the RC values for the battery will need to be formulated by you. The way to go about doing this is described in this paper: [An Accurate Electrical Battery Model Capable of Predicting Runtime and I–V Performance](http://rincon-mora.gatech.edu/publicat/jrnls/tec05_batt_mdl.pdf)
[image].
Source:
https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?214394-how-to-make-a-battery-model-of-NiMH-on-HSPICE

Note the dependent sources would be b-sources in LT-spice with nodes for the inputs.